# Side Navigation Bar Constraints programmatically in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, ios-autolayout

I tried few options to add constraints to my side nav bar but I couldn't do that. So I did:

```
func configureNavigationBar() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .darkGray
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

    navigationItem.title = "..."
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SideBar").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleMenuToggle))
}
```

That was the code to configure nav bar. I want to add constraints for image to left. I did this for my Side Bar Menu items like below.

```
addSubview(iconImageView)
    iconImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iconImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    iconImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true

    addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    descriptionLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    descriptionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
```

I want to able to do resize my nav bar also and put label into it something like these.

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` ??

Comment: This enables AutoLayout